# Link to embedded image from my xsl

Tags: c#, xslt

I have an xslt file that is embedded in my assembly. Also embedded in that assembly is an image.

How can i add a reference to that embedded image in my xsl file?

---

**UPDATED:**

I am using VS2008 and i add the image and the xslt as an embedded resource in the project. The output ultimately ends up being a pdf document.

Comment: Which programming language, which programming framework, which XSLT processor do you use? What kind of image is that, a binary one, or text one (like SVG)? What kind of output do you want to create with your XSLT?

Comment: Do you embed the stylesheet from VS (embedded resources)?

Comment: I updated my tags and added more info.. i sometimes forget that not everyone uses .net and Visual Studio :)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is probably a custom [XmlUrlResolver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlurlresolver.aspx) implementation

```
/// <summary>
/// Enables loading of xslt stylesheets from embedded resources.
/// </summary>
public class EmbeddedResourceResolver : XmlUrlResolver
{
    public override object GetEntity(
        Uri absoluteUri,
        string role,
        Type ofObjectToReturn)
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        return assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(absoluteUri.Segments.Last());
    }
}
```